# Delete Rows from HTML Table After x Rows PHP

Tags: php, html-table

**Html**

```
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>  //1st row

<tr><td></td></tr>  //2nd row

<tr><td></td></tr>  //3rd row

<tr><td></td></tr>  //4th row

<tr><td></td></tr>  //5th row
</table>
```

**What I want to do**

```
if (intval($rows) > 3) {

            delete all rows after 3rd row 
        }
```

**I am using below php code to get html page**

```
$index = substr_count(strtolower(file_get_contents('index.html')), '<tr>');
```

I hope my question clear enough to understand

**Full code**

```
<?php
        $htaccess = file_get_contents('index.html');
        $new_htaccess = str_replace('<table><tr><td>first row data</td></tr>', '<table><tr><td>first row data</td></tr><tr><td>sec row data</td></tr>', $htaccess);
        $pos = strpos($htaccess, $ssa);
        if ($pos == false) {
            file_put_contents('index.html', $new_htaccess);
        } else {

        }

        $index = substr_count(strtolower(file_get_contents('index.html')), '<tr>');

        if (intval($index) > 20) {
            //delete end rows and add a new one
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: +1 should have waited for that comment before going the hard way...

Comment: can you show the code for printing your rows to the screen - is it just a html table or are you using php to print it after retrieving data from a db?

Comment: it is just a html table....i have edited my main post you can see the full code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simplistic, and untested, method :

```
//--- create a new DOM document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
//--- load your file
$doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");
//--- point to the tables [0] means first table in the file
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

//--- get all the tr within the specified table
$tr = $tables->getElementsByTagName('tr');
//--- loop backwards
for( $x=count($tr)-1; $x>2 $x-- ) {
  //--- remove the node (not sure which one will work)
  $old = $tr->removeChild($tr[$x]);
  $old = $tr->removeChild( $tr->item($x) );
}
//--- save the new file
$doc->saveHTMLFile("/tmp/test.html");
```

References:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php

Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I would first extract the table using a regex such as `\<table>.+<\/table>\`, then 
strip the `<table> </table>` tags.

turn the string into array using `exlode` with `<tr>` as the delimiter
and finally reconstruct the table using the first 3 items of the array

that is how i would attempt it, not sure it is applicable to your case. obviously you are scraping another site, so it depends a lot of how consistent the code is.

Answer (score 0):

`jeff` posted a good solution, so if you are interested in using any 3rd party libraries.
I suggest you to use [`ganon.php`](https://github.com/msmuenchen/ganon/)

```
<?php
  require_once( "ganon.php" );
  // Your html
  $html = '<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  </table>';
  // load the html
  $html = str_get_dom( $html );
  // search for our table
  if ( $table = $html( "table", 0 ) ) {
    // get all rows which is after 3rd row, here 0 is 1, so 3rd row is 2
    if ( $rows = $html( "tr:gt(2)" ) ) {
      // loop through rows
      foreach( $rows as $row ) {
        // .... and delete them
        $row->delete();
      }
    }
  }
  // output your modified html
  echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can try as following

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type="text/javascript" ></script>

<?php
$html = '<table id="mytable">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  </table>';

echo $html;

?>

<script>
$(function() {
    var TRs = $("#mytable tr");
    for(i=0; i<TRs.length; i++) {
        if(i>=3) {
        $(TRs[i]).remove(); 
       }
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Answer is edited try it now. It is properly working for me